# ServerAlias changes URL in browser address bar

Tags: apache, virtualhost, redirect

I have this situation:

```
ServerName  sitea.domain.org
ServerAlias siteb.domain.org
```

If I put `siteb.domain.org` on my browser I'm redirected to the `sitea.domain.org` (which is what I want) but the URL on the address bar changes to `sitea.domain.org` (which I don't want).

How can I maintain the URL `siteb.domain.org`.

I've been looking and looking and I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Do you have an `.htaccess` file ? does it redirect any non-WWW requests to WWW ? Post your `.htaccess` if you have one.

Comment: I don't have a .htaccess defined.

My virtualhost is like this:

<VirtualHost *:80>

Redirect permanent / https://websitea.domain.org/

ServerName websitea.domain.org
ServerAlias websiteb.domain.org

</VirtualHost>

Thanks,
Ricardo

Comment: `Redirect permanent / websitea.domain.org` this is your problem, it redirects anything that hits your virtualhost to `websitea.domain.org`

Comment: Do I have an alternative? I want to redirect all the requests to https :/

Comment: But in the htaccess, does the serveralias work as I wanted to?

Comment: By removing the `Redirect permanent / websitea.domain.org` your alias will work the way you want after that you use the `.htaccess` to setup any other redirection or rules you want to apply for your specific domain or subdomains.